# ngx-bootstrap for angular - datepicker how do i change the theme color when nothing seems to work

Tags: javascript, angular, datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

I'm trying to change the color of the datepicker and it is not working

Here is the ngx-bootstrap datepicker  https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker

This is my html template

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="date">Date:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text"
               class="form-control"
               [minDate]="minDate"
               [maxDate]="maxDate"
               #dp="bsDatepicker"
               bsDatepicker 
               [(bsValue)]="bsValue">
        <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="dp.toggle()">Date Picker</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I was trying various things,  I do realize that this applyTheme is a function

```
colorTheme = 'theme-green';

bsConfig: Partial<BsDatepickerConfig>;

  applyTheme(pop: any) {
  // create new object on each property change
  // so Angular can catch object reference change
  this.bsConfig = Object.assign({}, { containerClass: this.colorTheme });
  setTimeout(() => {
    pop.show();
  });
}
```

Comment: And are you calling `applyTheme` anywhere?

Comment: @DanielB  -  no  ,  well I tried to in contructor and on OnInit  but it doesn't work

Comment: You will definitely have to call it somewhere if you expect it to do something, but I'm not sure it's the correct way to do it. Have you had a look at [this](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/docs/getting-started/bootstrap4.md)?

Answer (score 15):

Add the following lines in global styling file:  *styles.scss*

```
.bs-datepicker-body table td.week span 
{
  color: #2dfbcd !important; 
}

.bs-datepicker-body table td span.selected,
.bs-datepicker-head,
.bs-datepicker-head, .bs-datepicker button:active,
.bs-datepicker-body table td.selected span,
.bs-datepicker-body table td span[class*="select-"]:after,
.bs-datepicker-body table td[class*="select-"] span:after,
.bs-datepicker-body table td.active-week span:hover 
{
  background-color: #2dfbcd !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Adding
     `[bsConfig]="{containerClass:'theme-default'}"` to my component html file works fine for me.

The input element after addition of theme configuration:

```
<input type="text"
        placeholder="Select Time"
        class="form-control"
        bsDatepicker
        [bsConfig]="{containerClass:'theme-default'}"
        [(ngModel)]="startDateTime" (ngModelChange)="onStartDateTimeChange($event)">
```

I am using ngx-bootstrap version `3.2.0` with Angular `7.2.4`

Answer (score 1):

Add this script to the styles array `angular.json`, without this the bootstrap css won't be loaded and you will see basic buttons and the "calendar" overlayed onto your page

```
"./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
```

Answer (score 0):

-> **ngx bootstrap DatePicker**

component.ts (Set DatePicker configurations)

```
//ngxBootstrap datePicker config
bsConfig:Partial<BsDatepickerConfig> = {
  containerClass:'theme-red',
  dateInputFormat:'DD MMM YYYY'
}
```

template.html

```
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Date Of Birth"
         name="dateOfBirth" formControlName="dateOfBirth"
         bsDatepicker [bsConfig]="bsConfig"
         [ngClass]="{'is-invalid':f.dateOfBirth.touched && f.dateOfBirth.errors}">
```

Answer (score -4):

We can directly go to `bs-datepicker.config.js` file and there just change:

`this.containerClass = 'theme-dark-blue';`

or whatever color you want.

Comment: this is bad advice. If someone is working on a project and decided to do npm install on a fresh git then it will overwrite.  The correct way is through the BSDatePickerConfig as suggested above